# Custom Login and Password Reset for BuddyPress Website

Tags: plugins, login, front-end, buddypress

My website is a Community and Social Network website powered by BuddyPress.

But the way that BuddyPress is designed, is to work inside WordPress-- and use the default **WP-Login.Php** Page to handle Logins and Password Resets.

As a Community and Social Network website, it means that hundreds of people will be Logging in to Register and create Accounts on my website.

In 99% of the time, we don’t want these our Users to ever see the **WP-Admin** and the **WP-Login.Php** Pages.

In short, we don’t want these our users to even know that a **WP-Admin** and **WP-Login.Php** Page even exist.

The flow should follow that, even if people deliberately type “ ***mydomain.com/wp-admin*** ” or they deliberately type “ ***mydomain.com/wp-login.php*** ”, it should immediately and instantly redirect them to a **Custom Frontend Login Page** that we have created– and they should never see the “ **wp-admin** ” and “ **wp-login.php** ” Pages.

I have this PHP Code Snippet that already helps me handle the redirect on the frontend to my **Custom Login Page**:

```
// Redirect wp-login.php to the custom login page
function wbcom_custom_login_redirect($redirect_to, $request, $user) {
    // Is there a user to check?
    if (isset($user->roles) && is_array($user->roles) && in_array('subscriber', $user->roles)) {
        // Redirect them to the default place
        return home_url('/login'); // Updated to use /login
    } else {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'wbcom_custom_login_redirect', 10, 3);

// Redirect non-logged-in users accessing wp-login.php
function wbcom_redirect_non_logged_in_users() {
    if (!is_user_logged_in() && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-login.php') !== false && !isset($_POST['wp-submit']) && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) {
        $custom_login_url = home_url('/login'); // Updated to use /login
        wp_redirect($custom_login_url);
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('init', 'wbcom_redirect_non_logged_in_users');
```

This code works-- because it actually redirects my users to my Custom Login Page.

The challenge I have, is that I am not able to bypass the **WP-Login.Php** Page for **Password Reset**.

The reason I need to bypass the WP-Login.Php Page for Password Reset, is because the **WP-Login.Php** Page lands people on the **WP-Admin Page**.

And the **WP-Admin** Page confuses a lot of our users. It makes them think that there are probably 2 separate user flows on the website.

The overall intention, is to have a Form that can initiate Login, and also Password Reset.

And it must bypass the **WP-Login.Php** Page in the Password Reset process.

This Tutorial explains the process involved-- https://code.tutsplus.com/build-a-custom-wordpress-user-flow-part-3-password-reset--cms-23811t

And here is the full Tutorial that explain the process all the way from creating a Registration, Login and Password Reset Forms-- https://code.tutsplus.com/series/build-a-custom-wordpress-user-flow--cms-816

I need someone to help me go through that Tutorial, and convert the entire code from that Tutorial into a functional WordPress plugin-- that can actually do what I am looking to achieve.

Regards.